# java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://bustracker.rhcloud.com/webapi/test

Tags: android

I am sending JSON String to the server. the Postdata class is being called from the service class where the service class is being launched from the onCreate() method in the MainActivity. I have tested the code of `PostData` class before and it works well. I am just getting the following warning and I am not getting response from the server any more. What does that mean?

I appreciate any help

**Warning:**

```
05-30 19:15:22.791: W/System.err(8371): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://bustracker.rhcloud.com/webapi/test
05-30 19:15:22.791: W/System.err(8371):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
05-30 19:15:22.791: W/System.err(8371):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
05-30 19:15:22.801: W/System.err(8371):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
05-30 19:15:22.801: W/System.err(8371):     at com.bustracker.PostData$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(PostData.java:83)
05-30 19:15:22.801: W/System.err(8371):     at com.bustracker.PostData$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(PostData.java:1)
05-30 19:15:22.801: W/System.err(8371):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-30 19:15:22.801: W/System.err(8371):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-30 19:15:22.801: W/System.err(8371):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-30 19:15:22.801: W/System.err(8371):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-30 19:15:22.801: W/System.err(8371):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-30 19:15:22.811: W/System.err(8371):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**PostData class:**

```
public class PostData {
    String jSONString;
    private AsyncTaskCallback callback;


    public PostData(AsyncTaskCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public String getjSONString() {
        return jSONString;

    }

    public void setjSONString(String jSONString) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;
    }

    public void post_data(String jSONString, Context context) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;

        new MyAsyncTask(context).execute(jSONString);

    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> {
        final Context mContext;
        ArrayList<Integer> routes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        double distance;

        public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Integer> doInBackground(String... params) {
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                System.out.println("The output of : doInBackground "
                        + params[0]);

                URL myUrl = new URL(
                        "https://bustracker.rhcloud.com/webapi/test");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.connect();


                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");

                }

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                JSONStore data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), JSONStore.class);

                routes = data.getRoutes();
                distance = data.getDistance();
                System.out.println("The output of the StringBulder: "
                        + sb.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                        return null;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Integer> result) {

             if (routes != null && !routes.isEmpty()) {
            callback.onAsyncTaskFinished(routes, distance);
             }else{
                 Log.e("123", "Avoiding null pointer in the PostData class, the routes are null!!!");
             }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Well, that server doesn't seem to exist. Leastways, requesting https://bustracker.rhcloud.com/webapi/test does not seem to work. Another possibility would be that you can reach the server, but it returned a 404 error.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have called the link by POSTMAN and I can reach the server and I am getting a response

Comment: Perhaps your device or emulator cannot reach that server.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have created another class with the same procedure like in the PostData class to get data (and not to post data). I am not calling this class from anywhere but without these changing I am getting a response from the server?!